# How to conditionally stop data-toggle for pills in twitter-bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="moduleList">
    <li class="">
        <a href="#" onclick="return loadModule(this)" data-toggle="pill" data-value="user">User</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" onclick="return loadModule(this)" data-toggle="pill" data-value="Blog">Blog</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have the above bootstrap pill in my website. The active item changes and the script execute to load the active item in the page. In some condition I don't want to change the active item and the decision will be made inside the onclick function loadModule(). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Remove **data-toggle="pill"** from your markup, then change the class of the selected 'li' to active or empty within 'loadModule'.  Here's an example:

```js
function loadModule(a) {

  //your logic/////

  $('#liUser').attr('class', '');
  $('#liBlog').attr('class', 'active');
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="moduleList">
  <li id="liUser" class="">
    <a href="#" onclick="return loadModule(this)" data-value="user">User</a>
  </li>
  <li id="liBlog">
    <a href="#" onclick="return loadModule(this)" data-value="Blog">Blog</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if is useful for you. Try this using jQuery:

```
$(document).delegate('.nav-pills li a', 'click', function () {
  $('.nav-pills li').removeClass('active');
  this.parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Then remove click and data-toggle attributes. You can add some logic inside of delegate callback.